# How to override gorm many2many fields in query?

Tags: go, go-gorm

```golang
type User struct {
    ID     int `json:"id"`
    UserID int `json:"user_id"`
    Languages []Language `gorm:"many2many:user_language_tab;ForeignKey:UserID;References:LanguageID"`
}

type UserLanguage struct {
    ID         int
    LanguageID int `gorm:"ForeignKey:LanguageID;References:Languages.LanguageID"`
    UserID     int `gorm:"ForeignKey:UserID;References:Users.UserID"`
}

type Language struct {
    ID         int
    LanguageID int
    Name       string
}

func (User) TableName() string {
    return "user_tab"
}


func (Teacher) TableName() string {
    return "teacher_tab"
}


func (Language) TableName() string {
    return "language_tab"
}

var u []User
err := db.Debug().Preload("Languages").Find(&u).Error
```

there are the models, User join UserLanguage on UserID and join Language on LanguageID.

I override the tags like https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key

But it report `Error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'user_language_tab.user_user_id' in 'where clause'`

I want to ask:

- How to modify the code to make it works ?
- What dose the `joinForeignKey` and `joinReferences do`? It's necessary for me?
- If I want to find []Language and preload the Users, Does the tag need to be changed?